# Nuxt SSR rebuild of routes.json on the fly (production)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no...but is there any way to initiate a rebuild of .nuxt/routes.json and .nuxt/router.js file on the fly, while the production server is running from within native nuxt functionality.  nuxt.config.js router.extendRoutes builds the routes at the initial build time - haven't found a way of doing an update while the server is still running.  Would prefer not to have to do a new npm build.

```js
// Router middleware
router: {
    middleware: ['router-agent', 'ssr-promises'],
    async extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
        // pulls in routes from external file
        await customRoutes(routes, resolve)
    }
},
```

We have a selection of custom routes we need to build from a CMS

```js
// extendRoutes snippet
let pageRoutes = require('./routes-bkp.json')

try {
  const { data: { pages } } = await getPagesForRoutes.queryCMS()
  pageRoutes = pages
  console.log('Route Request Succeeded.')
} catch {
  console.log('Route Request Succeeded.!  Using backup version.')
}

pageRoutes.forEach(({ slug }) => {
  routes.unshift({
    name: slug,
    path: `/:page(${slug})`,
    component: '~/pages/_page'
  })
})
```

The purpose of all this is have a client build trigger in the CMS, when they update their pages.

More info about router.js here:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt

and about extending the router here:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#extending-the-router

Comment: For `target: 'static'` or `'server'`?

Comment: Also, did you checked the [preview mode](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/live-preview/)?

Comment: Thanks @kissu, yes, target: 'server'.  Preview mode doesn't resolve this as refreshes individual pages, we need refresh (or add to start/end of array) all the routes for the whole site.

Comment: It should work out of the box if I'm not mistaken. Like if you have a `/products/_slug`, you could send anything there and it will render it each time you reach the server. You can also [slugify the whole thing](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes) if the depth can be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, for the majority of use cases this is brilliant.  Some edge cases though require router extensions - https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#extending-the-router.  This is the case here.

Comment: Never tried it myself but since it's [working for static](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#function-which-returns-a-promise), I guess it should work for server too.

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7437#issuecomment-966098019) is related to your question I think.

Comment: Did you try [using build.watch](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#watch)? You can generate a `json` file on the server that will contain information about the dynamic routes of your cms, import that file in your extendRoutes and build.watch that file in case it doesn't trigger a rebuild

Comment: Thanks @Arik, perfect I think this will solve it!

Comment: Thanks I'll compose an answer

Answer (score 3):

[build.watch](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#watch) might assist you to trigger a server restart on a file change.

You can also generate a json file on the server that will contain information about the dynamic routes of your CMS, import that file in your `extendRoutes` and [build.watch](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#watch) that file in case it doesn't trigger a restart when it's changed

For production, you can [use nuxt programmatically](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/nuxt/) to expose a server middleware that listens to requests and restarts the server

Comment: Does this one work in production? Also, is it needed? Can't you just ping an API?

Comment: @kissu answer updated

Comment: Damn, dope! Amazing answer man. Didn't knew this was possible.